# Activiti - How do you get the information, such as "values", from a custom form type that extends EnumFormType?

Tags: java, jsp, activiti

I've created a custom form type that extends `EnumFormType` and I presumed that I'd be able to use the method `getInformation("values")` but it returns `null`. Basically I need to be able to get the values that are set in the form property window in Activiti designer for eclipse.

My custom form type:

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.activiti.engine.impl.form.EnumFormType;

public class ImpactedSitesFormType  extends EnumFormType {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String TYPE_NAME = "impactedSite";

    public ImpactedSitesFormType() {

        this(null);

    }

     public ImpactedSitesFormType(Map<String, String> values) {
    super(values);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     }

     public String getName() {
       return TYPE_NAME;
     }

     public Object convertFormValueToModelValue(String propertyValue) {
       Integer impactedSite = Integer.valueOf(propertyValue);
       return impactedSite;
     }

     public String convertModelValueToFormValue(Object modelValue) {
       if (modelValue == null) {
         return null;
       }
       return modelValue.toString();

     }

   }
```

My JSP code:

```
<c:if test="${type == 'impactedSite'}">
    <select name="${property.getId()}">
        <c:forEach var="entry" items='${property.getType().getInformation("values")}'>
            <option value="${entry.key}">${entry.value}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select><br /><br />
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the very same issue today -- here are my two cents:

Most likely, you are registering your custom type in `activiti.cfg.xml` like:

```
<property name="customFormTypes">
  <list>
    <bean class="org.yourdomain.ImpactedSitesFormType" />
    ...
  </list>
</property>
```

Right? This will create an instance using the default constructor, in which you explicitly set the values to `null`.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to encourage Activiti to call your other constructor. Instead, you have to use a custom `FormTypes` implementation and do the initialization manually:

```
public class CustomFormTypes extends FormTypes {

    public CustomFormTypes() {
        // register Activiti's default form types
        addFormType(new StringFormType());
        addFormType(new LongFormType());
        addFormType(new DateFormType("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        addFormType(new BooleanFormType());
        addFormType(new DoubleFormType());
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractFormType parseFormPropertyType(FormProperty formProperty) {
        if (ImpactedSitesFormType.TYPE_NAME.equals(formProperty.getType())) {
            Map<String, String> values = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            for (FormValue formValue : formProperty.getFormValues()) {
                values.put(formValue.getId(), formValue.getName());
            }
            return new ImpactedSitesFormType(values);
        } else {
            // delegate construction of all other types
            return super.parseFormPropertyType(formProperty);
        }
    }

}
```

To make your `CustomFormTypes` class known to Activiti, configure it in `activiti.cfg.xml`:

```
<property name="formTypes">
    <bean class="org.yourdomain.CustomFormTypes" />
</property>
```

[This blog post](http://mwenus.blogspot.ch/2014/02/how-to-create-custom-form-property_13.html) and its [example code on GitHub](https://github.com/mateuszwenus/activiti-custom-form-types) helped me a lot!